# usbser.sys on Windows 7 Embedded, installed but not found

Tags: serial-port, driver, windows-7-embedded

I've installed a barcode reader on a Windows 7 machine: it is configurated with virtual serial port mode.
At the initial moment the driver was not found; looking in the Windows folders I did not find the usbser.sys file.
So I installed the following package:

```
pkgmgr /ip /m:winemb-inf-mdmcpq.cab
```

Looking in the Windows folders now I find the usbser.sys in a couple of locations such as System32\DriverStore\FileRepository... and winsxs... folders.
Still the driver for the barcode reader is not found.
I took a look inside the device and it has as compatible IDs:

```
USB\Class_02&SubClass_02&Prot_01
USB\Class_02&SubClass_02
USB\Class_02
```

Is it not sufficient to try to locate the usbser.sys driver?

Comment: It's a small possibility, but this article may be helpful. [Inf file can't find usbser.sys in Windows 7 only](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41928144/9014308)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved writing a inf file where I specified the USB VID and PID of the device.
In this way the serial driver was loaded and a port number was assigned.